# CONCATENATE to ignore blank results if one cell is missing

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I do a Concatenate/Textjoin to output blank results if just one cell value is missing (I need all cell values to be present)? This condition goes for N1388, P1388, K1388, and L1388.

```
=CONCATENATE( "Valued Customer, your Map(s) request is ready at this link. ", 
              "Please retrieve within 7 days. ",
              N1388, " ",
              "map(s) will be billed for ",
              P1388, ". "
              K1388, " ",
              L1388, ". ",
              "Please contact a service planner if necessary."
)
```

Comment: Add an `if` and `or`?

Answer (score 1):

This formula should do what you require, I have also tidied up some of the unnecessary text joins used for the spaces.

`=IF(OR(ISBLANK(N1388),ISBLANK(P1388),ISBLANK(K1388),ISBLANK(L1388)),"",CONCATENATE("Valued Customer, your Map(s) request is ready at this link. Please retrieve within 7 days. ",N1388," map(s) will be billed for ",P1388,". ",K1388," ",L1388,". Please contact a service planner if necessary."))`

Comment: Ah that did the trick, thank you!! =IF(OR(N1388="",P1388="",K1388="",L1388=""),"",CONCATENATE("Valued Customer, your Map(s) request is ready at this link. Please retrieve within 7 days. ",N1388," map(s) will be billed for ",P1388,". ",K1388," ",L1388,". Please contact an service planner if necessary."))

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(OR(N1388="",P1388="",K1388="",L1388=""),"",CONCATENATE("Valued Customer, your Map(s) request is ready at this link. Please retrieve within 7 days. ",N1388," map(s) will be billed for ",P1388,". ",K1388," ",L1388,". Please contact an service planner if necessary.")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @5202456's answer, but mine will check for blanks which are a result of formulas. It is also slightly more efficient as the `OR` does not short circuit and all the conditions will be checked, even if the first one returns true.

```
=IF(N1388="",""
    IF(P1388="","",
        IF(K1388="","",
            IF(L1388="","",
                CONCATENATE( "Valued Customer, your Map(s) request is ready at this link. ", 
                              "Please retrieve within 7 days. ",
                              N1388, " ",
                              "map(s) will be billed for ",
                              P1388, ". "
                              K1388, " ",
                              L1388, ". ",
                              "Please contact a service planner if necessary."
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```